# MariaDB Galera Installation

Tags: mariadb, galera

I am trying to install MariaDB Galera Cluster 11.1.11 on RHEL 7.
Is there any pointers for Installation of MariaDB Galera Cluster 11.1.11 on RHEL 7.
I mainly interested in MariaDB 11.1.11 with tar ball and galera with RPM.

Thanks and Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

The current GA release of MariaDB Galera Cluster is 10.4.2. Version 11.1.11 does not yet exist.